# Embedding a UIScrollView inside of a UIPageViewController and disabling pageView swiping?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikit, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIView` subclass (a graph) embedded inside of a `UIScrollview` inside of a `UIViewController` which is one of a `UIPageViewController`s pages... I'm trying to disable scrolling of the `UIPageViewController` so that the user scan scroll to see the far left of the graph without paging back.  How can I do this?  Is a ScrollView even the correct tool for this job?  [image]

```
class HistoricalHealthDataViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var graphScrollView: UIScrollView!

    @IBOutlet weak var hockeyTrackerGraphView: HockeyTrackerGraphView! {
        didSet {
            self.hockeyTrackerGraphView.graphableObjects = HFRGraphableObjects
        }
    }


    var HFRGraphableObjects: [HockeyTrackerGraphableObject] = [] 





    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        graphScrollView.delegate = self


    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        if let parentPageViewController = parent as? HistoricalPageViewController {

            for gestureRecognizer in parentPageViewController.gestureRecognizers {
                print("gestureRecognizer")
                gestureRecognizer.isEnabled = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the code for it, but I'm assuming you implement `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` protocol and somewhere you have the methods:

```
func pageViewController(UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
}

func pageViewController(UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
}
```

If you arrange for those methods to return nil while paging is disabled, the page view won't scroll to a different page.